# first order and higher degree differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Can someone please solve this differential equation with detailed solution

$$y= 2x\frac{dy}{dx} + y^3\bigg(\frac{dy}{dx}\bigg)^3$$

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean: $$y(x)=2xy'(x)+y(x)^3y'''(x)$$?

Comment: The second factor in the second term in R.H.S is (y'(x))^3 and not y'''(x).

Comment: So this:$$y(x)=2xy'(x)+y(x)^3\left(y'(x)\right)^3$$

Comment: yes. thats it..

Comment: Yes I tried it but the factor (1+ 3(y^2)(y'(x)^3)) did not get cancelled

Comment: If it were $y=2xy'+y^2y'^3$ one could substitute $v=y^2$ to obtain the Clairaut equation $v=xv'+\frac18v'^3$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$y=2x\dfrac{dy}{dx}+y^3\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^3$

$2x\dfrac{dy}{dx}=y-y^3\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^3$

$x=\dfrac{y}{2\dfrac{dy}{dx}}-\dfrac{y^3}{2}\left(\dfrac{dy}{dx}\right)^2$

Follow the method in http://science.fire.ustc.edu.cn/download/download1/book%5Cmathematics%5CHandbook%20of%20Exact%20Solutions%20for%20Ordinary%20Differential%20EquationsSecond%20Edition%5Cc2972_fm.pdf#page=234:

Let $t=\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ ,

Then $\left(\dfrac{1}{2}+\dfrac{3y^2t^3}{2}\right)\dfrac{dy}{dt}=-\dfrac{y}{2t}-y^3t^2$

$(3t^3y^2+1)\dfrac{dy}{dt}=-2t^2y^3-\dfrac{y}{t}$

Let $s=t^3$ ,

Then $\dfrac{dy}{dt}=\dfrac{dy}{ds}\dfrac{ds}{dt}=3t^2\dfrac{dy}{ds}$

$\therefore(3t^3y^2+1)3t^2\dfrac{dy}{ds}=-2t^2y^3-\dfrac{y}{t}$

$(3t^3y^2+1)\dfrac{dy}{ds}=-\dfrac{2y^3}{3}-\dfrac{y}{3t^3}$

$(3sy^2+1)\dfrac{dy}{ds}=-\dfrac{2y^3}{3}-\dfrac{y}{3s}$

Let $u=\dfrac{1}{y^2}$ ,

Then $\dfrac{du}{ds}=-\dfrac{2}{y^3}\dfrac{dy}{ds}$

$\therefore-\dfrac{y^3(3sy^2+1)}{2}\dfrac{du}{ds}=-\dfrac{2y^3}{3}-\dfrac{y}{3s}$

$\left(\dfrac{1}{y^2}+3s\right)\dfrac{du}{ds}=\dfrac{2}{3sy^4}+\dfrac{4}{3y^2}$

$(u+3s)\dfrac{du}{ds}=\dfrac{2u^2}{3s}+\dfrac{4u}{3}$

$\left(\dfrac{u}{s}+3\right)\dfrac{du}{ds}=\dfrac{2u^2}{3s^2}+\dfrac{4u}{3s}$

Luckily this becomes a first-order homogeneous ODE.

Let $v=\dfrac{u}{s}$ ,

Then $u=sv$

$\dfrac{du}{ds}=s\dfrac{dv}{ds}+v$

$\therefore(v+3)\left(s\dfrac{dv}{ds}+v\right)=\dfrac{2v^2}{3}+\dfrac{4v}{3}$

$s\dfrac{dv}{ds}+v=\dfrac{2v^2+4v}{3(v+3)}$

$s\dfrac{dv}{ds}=\dfrac{2v^2+4v}{3(v+3)}-v$

$s\dfrac{dv}{ds}=-\dfrac{v(v+5)}{3(v+3)}$

$\dfrac{ds}{s}=-\dfrac{3(v+3)}{v(v+5)}~dv$

$\int\dfrac{ds}{s}=-\int\left(\dfrac{9}{5v}+\dfrac{6}{5(v+5)}\right)~dv$

$\ln s=-\dfrac{9\ln v}{5}-\dfrac{6\ln(v+5)}{5}+c$

$\dfrac{1}{s^5}=c_1v^9(v+5)^6$

$\dfrac{1}{s^5}=c_1\dfrac{u^9}{s^9}\left(\dfrac{u}{s}+5\right)^6$

$s^{10}=c_1u^9(u+5s)^6$

$t^{30}=\dfrac{c_1}{y^{18}}\left(\dfrac{1}{y^2}+5t^3\right)^6$

$t^{30}=\dfrac{c_1(5y^2t^3+1)^6}{y^{30}}$

$y^5t^5=C(5y^2t^3+1)$

Hence $\begin{cases}y=2xt+y^3t^3\\y^5t^5=C(5y^2t^3+1)\end{cases}$ or $\begin{cases}y=2xt+y^3t^3\\Cy^5t^5=5y^2t^3+1\end{cases}$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: This ODE does have a Lie point symmetry. The infinitesimal generator is given by

$$X=\dfrac{5}{3}x\partial_x+y\partial y$$ 
Use the method of canonical coordinate

$$Xr(x,y)=0 \qquad Xs(x,y)=1$$

to obtain the substitution (we choose the most simple solution)

$$y(r,s)=r\exp(s)$$
$$x(r,s)=\exp\left[\dfrac{5}{3}s\right].$$

Then determine the derivative in the new coordinates:
$$\dfrac{dy(r,s)}{dx(r,s)}=\dfrac{\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial r}dr+\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial s}ds}{\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial r}dr+\dfrac{\partial x}{\partial s}ds}=\dfrac{\exp(s)+r\exp(s)s'}{\dfrac{5}{3}\exp(\dfrac{5}{3}s)s'}$$

Substitute the same expression on the right-hand side of the ODE and you will obtain an ODE $s'(r)=g(r)$, which boils down to a "simple" integration. I wrote "simple" because it might happen that you cannot find an explicit solution for the integral.

Maple returns after simplification:

$$27\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}r}}s \left( r \right)  \right) ^{3}{
r}^{6}+81\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}r}}s \left( r \right) 
 \right) ^{2}{r}^{5}+81\, \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}r}}s \left( r
 \right)  \right) {r}^{4}+25\,r \left( {\frac {\rm d}{{\rm d}r}}s
 \left( r \right)  \right) ^{3}+27\,{r}^{3}+150\, \left( {\frac 
{\rm d}{{\rm d}r}}s \left( r \right)  \right) ^{2}=0
$$

This is a polynomial in $ds/dr$ of degree 3. Solve the cubic equation (by [Cardano's formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CubicFormula.html)) to obtain three first order separable ODEs for each solution of the form $s'(r)=g(r)$.